# Chart chart bar colour for maximum

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I've got a tablix with embedded sparklines in the first column (but outside the group that makes up the other columns of the table): these are bar charts.

X-axis is date (30 days) and Y-axis is a value measure called MyMeasue.

I'm trying to change the colour of the bar which is the maximum valued bar for each chart.

The DataSet which is feeding the chart is called "SetX".

In the chart I have used an expression for the `Series Properties` `Fill` property:

```
=
IIF(
    Fields!MyMeasure.Value
       = Max(Fields!MyMeasure,"SetX")
  ,"Red"
  ,"DarkGray"
)
```

This is highlighting the wrong column. Is there an obvious error in this expression?

Comment: Should it not be `= Max(Fields!MyMeasure.Value,"SetX")`? (note **.Value**)

Comment: @GarethD apologies: when anonymizing the expression I forgot the .Value - it is in the production expression. Turns out that the expression wasn't the problem - it was because the data is via an mdx script so that dates are hitting the charts as strings and therefore not in the correct order: I changed the ordering to be dependent on the keys and all is good now. (maybe I'll delete this question)